# How do I get the opposite side of an association on this foreign_key association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have a `membership` model that has the following associations:

```
class Membership < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :family_tree
  belongs_to :member
  belongs_to :inviter, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "user_id"
  belongs_to :invited, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "invited_id"    
end
```

This is the schema:

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: memberships
#
#  id                      :integer          not null, primary key
#  family_tree_id          :integer
#  user_id                 :integer
#  relation                :string(255)
#  member_id               :integer
#  invited_id              :integer
#
```

And on my `User` model, I have the following:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :memberships
end
```

So I can successfully assign 2 different users to 1 record, for instance:

```
[7] pry(#<RSpec::ExampleGroups::User>)> membership
=> #<Membership id: 90, family_tree_id: 1049, user_id: 779, created_at: "2015-10-29 15:24:02", updated_at: "2015-10-29 15:24:02", relation: "sister", member_id: 108, connection_sent_at: nil, connection_responded_at: nil, connect_send_limit: nil, connect_times_sent: nil, connected: nil, connect_type: nil, request_status: nil, connection_removed_at: nil, invited_id: 777>
[8] pry(#<RSpec::ExampleGroups::User>)> membership.family_tree
=> #<FamilyTree id: nil, name: "Enrico McGlynn", user_id: 777, created_at: "2015-10-29 15:24:02", updated_at: "2015-10-29 15:24:02">
[11] pry(#<RSpec::ExampleGroups::User>)> membership.inviter
=> #<User id: nil, email: "odell@lowe.net", encrypted_password: "$2a$04$Ke.1sQ9mZ2ZP0Hxamg6NS.6zUoEHyolPbKJ1UfAlils...", reset_password_token: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil, remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: 0, current_sign_in_at: nil, last_sign_in_at: nil, current_sign_in_ip: nil, last_sign_in_ip: nil, created_at: "2015-10-29 15:24:02", updated_at: "2015-10-29 15:24:02", first_name: "Audie", confirmation_token: nil, confirmed_at: "2015-10-29 15:23:57", confirmation_sent_at: nil, unconfirmed_email: nil, invitation_relation: "quibusdam", avatar: nil, invitation_token: nil, invitation_created_at: nil, invitation_sent_at: nil, invitation_accepted_at: nil, invitation_limit: nil, invited_by_id: nil, invited_by_type: nil, invitations_count: 0, bio: "Quibusdam est laborum cupiditate modi et est. Nece...", last_name: "Feil", gender: 1>
[12] pry(#<RSpec::ExampleGroups::User>)> membership.invited
=> #<User id: nil, email: "jalon_greenfelder@hudson.name", encrypted_password: "$2a$04$jlFrLS6UlcchaJlsOAv4ne/5nYSxH.7Zdsvk5WZMd1w...", reset_password_token: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil, remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: 0, current_sign_in_at: nil, last_sign_in_at: nil, current_sign_in_ip: nil, last_sign_in_ip: nil, created_at: "2015-10-29 15:24:02", updated_at: "2015-10-29 15:24:02", first_name: "Annamae", confirmation_token: nil, confirmed_at: "2015-10-29 15:23:57", confirmation_sent_at: nil, unconfirmed_email: nil, invitation_relation: "eveniet", avatar: nil, invitation_token: nil, invitation_created_at: nil, invitation_sent_at: nil, invitation_accepted_at: nil, invitation_limit: nil, invited_by_id: nil, invited_by_type: nil, invitations_count: 0, bio: "Ut explicabo omnis facilis et. Dolor sunt enim et....", last_name: "Kshlerin", gender: 1>
```

The issue I run into is when I am trying to go the other way, i.e. from that user record to find all the `memberships` associated with it. It returns an empty array.

```
[1] pry(#<RSpec::ExampleGroups::User>)> u1
=> #<User id: nil, email: "jalon_greenfelder@hudson.name", encrypted_password: "$2a$04$jlFrLS6UlcchaJlsOAv4ne/5nYSxH.7Zdsvk5WZMd1w...", reset_password_token: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil, remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: 0, current_sign_in_at: nil, last_sign_in_at: nil, current_sign_in_ip: nil, last_sign_in_ip: nil, created_at: "2015-10-29 15:24:02", updated_at: "2015-10-29 15:24:02", first_name: "Annamae", confirmation_token: nil, confirmed_at: "2015-10-29 15:23:57", confirmation_sent_at: nil, unconfirmed_email: nil, invitation_relation: "eveniet", avatar: nil, invitation_token: nil, invitation_created_at: nil, invitation_sent_at: nil, invitation_accepted_at: nil, invitation_limit: nil, invited_by_id: nil, invited_by_type: nil, invitations_count: 0, bio: "Ut explicabo omnis facilis et. Dolor sunt enim et....", last_name: "Kshlerin", gender: 1>
[9] pry(#<RSpec::ExampleGroups::User>)> u1.memberships
=> []
```

How do I get `user.memberships` to return the memberships associated with `user_id and invited_id` on the `memberships` model?

Answer (score 0):

`user.memberships` is equivalent to `Membership.where(user_id: user.id)`. You should note that the foreign_key in the `memberships` for an association with the `User` model is by default `user_id`. To solve your issue:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 #user.memberships will be equivalent to Membership.where(user_id: user.id)
 has_many :memberships

 #user.invited_memberships will be equivalent to Membership.where(inviter_id: user.id) 
 has_many :invited_memberships, class_name: Membership, foreign_key: :inviter_id

  def all_memberships
    #this will return the memberships associated with the user_id and the inviter_id
    #you may want to move this to the Membership model
    Membership.where('user_id = ? OR inviter_id = ?', self.id, self.id)
  end     
end
```

Comment: This makes sense. The one issue I guess is before I even get to the others....y does `has_many :memberships` not return any records despite there being records with `user_id`.

Comment: One thing I noticed is that the `user.id` for each user record returned is `nil`. Could that be causing this issue? If so, how do I fix it?

Comment: But the weird thing is, why does it find the actual record?. i.e. when you do `membership.inviter` it returns the user record with a `nil` id.

Comment: Is it an issue with pry only? Do your tests pass?

Comment: Nope....tests fail...I am using an rspec flavor of pry that is allowing me to run those commands in the scope of the failing test.